# Saving related object with composedObject and doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm having trouble trying to save related data using doctrine and a composedobject

these are my entities

this is my employee entity

```
<?php
namespace Nomina\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation;
use Nomina\Entity\EmpleadosDetalles;


/**
 * Empleado
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="empleado")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Annotation\Hydrator("Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty")
 * @Annotation\Name("EmpleadoForm")
 */
class Empleado
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
 * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true"})
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Nombre"})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"class":"form-control"})
 * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"NotEmpty","options":{"messages":{"isEmpty":"no debe estar vacio"}}})
 */
private $nombre;

/**
 * @var \EmpleadosDetalles $detalles
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Nomina\Entity\EmpleadosDetalles", mappedBy="empleado", cascade={"persist"})
 * @Annotation\ComposedObject("Nomina\Entity\EmpleadosDetalles")
 */
private $detalles;

/**
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Submit")
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"value":"Procesar"})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"class":"btn btn-primary"})
 */
public $submit;

public function __construct() {
    $this->detalles = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getDetalles() {
    return $this->detalles;
}

/**
 * Set nombre
 *
 * @param string $nombre
 * @return Empleado
 */
public function setNombre($nombre)
{
    $this->nombre = $nombre;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nombre
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getNombre()
{
    return $this->nombre;
}
}
```

this is my Details entity, which belongs to a employee

```
<?php
namespace Nomina\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation;
/**
 * EmpleadosDetalles
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="empleadosDetalles", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_empleado", columns={"idEmpleado"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Annotation\Hydrator("Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty")
 * @Annotation\Name("EmpleadoDetallesForm")
 */
class EmpleadosDetalles
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="salario", type="int", nullable=false)
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
 * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true"})
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Salario"})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"class":"form-control"})
 * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"NotEmpty","options":{"messages":{"isEmpty":"no debe estar vacio"}}})
 */
private $salario = '0';

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="numero", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
 * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true"})
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Numero"})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"class":"form-control"})
 * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"NotEmpty","options":{"messages":{"isEmpty":"no debe estar vacio"}}})
 */
private $numero;


/**
* @ORM\Column(name="idEmpleado", type="integer", length=11, nullable=false)
*/
private $idEmpleado;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nomina\Entity\Empleado", inversedBy="detalles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idEmpleado", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
 protected $empleado;

/**
 * Set salario
 *
 * @param integer $salario
 * @return EmpleadosDetalles
 */
public function setSalario($salario)
{
    $this->salario = $salario;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get salario
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getSalario()
{
    return $this->salario;
}

/**
 * Set numero
 *
 * @param string $numero
 * @return EmpleadosDetalles
 */
public function setNumero($numero)
{
    $this->numero = $numero;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get numero
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getNumero()
{
    return $this->numero;
}


public function setEmpleado(Empleado $empleado)
{
    $this->empleado = $empleado;
    return $this;
}

public function getEmpleado()
{
    return $this->empleado;
}

}
```

and this is my controller action

```
public function addAction() {
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $empleado = new Empleado();

    $entityManager = $this->entityManager();
    $builder = new DoctrineAnnotationBuilder($entityManager);
    $form = $builder->createForm($empleado);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->bind($empleado);
        $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager,'Nomina\Entity\Empleado'));
        $form->setValidationGroup('nombre');
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager->persist($empleado);
            $entityManager->flush();
            $this->redirect()->toRoute('empleado');
        } else {
            $view->messages = $form->getMessages();
        }
    }
    $view->form = $form;
    return $view;
}
```

I'm not getting any error, the employee it's saving in the table, but the details table is not getting populated. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sur $empleado->getDetalles() is not empty ?

Comment: it's empty, this is what I get on print_r

    Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection Object ( [_elements:Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection:private] => Array ( ) )

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your problems are in inputFilter/validator. That something is wrong in your @annotation for validation/filtering and because of this the inputFilter is filtering all the data for `$detalles` meaning there is nothing but an empty array to hydrate.

First check if all data is in your post:

```
var_dump($request->getPost());
```

Then try to hydrate once without using the forms inputFilter for filtering/validation.
Like this:

```
$empleado = new Empleado();
$hydrator = new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager,'Nomina\Entity\Empleado');
$data = $request->getPost()
$empleado = $hydrator($data, $empleado);
$entityManager->persist($empleado);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Check if that works.
Than at least you know if the problem is in your form validation/filtering or somewhere else in your entity definitions.